# How can I select obects one by one on Array

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Array I want to select one by one

Comment: You need to apply the modifier in order to tweak array instances individually. Click on the arrow next to the cross on the modifier header and choose Apply.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.